# Ruby On Rails multi selector with many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, html-select

I have two models

***Project*** which has has_and_belongs_to_many :users

and

***Users*** which has has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

in project view I have a form that has a selector where I want to try and assign multiple users to a project.

```
<%= select_tag("project[users]",  options_for_select(@users, @project_users), {:multiple=>true, :size=>6} )%>
```

in my project controller the variables that get used in the select are

```
@project_users = @project.users.collect { |user| user.id}
@users = User.all.collect { |user| ["#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}", user.id] }
```

which all out puts

```
<select id="project_users" multiple="multiple" name="project[users][]" size="6">
   <option value="#<User:0x007f567cb7f078>">User1</option>
   <option value="#<User:0x007f567cb7e9c0>">User2</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that this is not the equivalent to

```
@some_project << [User(#), User(#)]
```

("note User(#) represent class instance")

instead its the equivalent to

```
@some_project << ["1", "2"]
```

The problem is the user instance gets converted to string but not back into the instance again.

Which does not work and will throw an error as

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ProjectsController#update
User(#70004716784160) expected, got String(#4266680)
```

How can I make this work correctly?

Comment: In your update method on the `ProjectsController`, couldn't you just do a User.find(user.id) with each of those ids and then build the associated users from there? (That's assuming that the `option value="1"` value is the User's id.)

Comment: I dont think that is as dry as seeing if I can pass the arguments properly formatted.

Comment: Good point, but it may work as a temporary solution until you can find a more elegant one.

Comment: If I cant find a way to properly format the arguments I may have no other choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your User model:

```
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].join(" ")
end
```

In your controller

```
@users = User.all
```

In your view:

```
<%= select_tag('project[user_ids]', options_from_collection_for_select(@users, 'id', 'full_name'), { :multiple => true, :size => 6 }) %>
```

Then you can just use

```
@project.user_ids = params[:project][:user_ids]
```

or

```
@project.update_attributes(params[:project])
```

for assignment.

Comment: This will cause the ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch because the arguments are strings. This is in a sense what I'm already doing. though you cleaned up my select tag code :)

the issue is I need to convert the strings back into instances  on the update then manually assign.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem because project.user_ids expects ids, not records (and I believe they will convert them to integers [ '5' to 5 ]). If you try to do project.users = params[:project][:user_ids] you'll get a type mismatch, but if you set project.user_ids there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Your right, I didn't realize that user_ids was a method, nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send the instance. It can change between the render of the form and the submit. The conversion to string is a one way operation, as it refers to the object's unique id (like memory address), not it's properties or database identifier! As it is not part of the ActiveRecord but the ruby's object base. When the data of the form is returned, the instance is not in the memory, so you can't convert it back, even if it would be possible otherwise.

Stick to the plain old way:

```
@project_users = @project.users.collect { |user| user.id}
@users = User.all.collect { |user| ["#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}", user.id] }
```

And when the data is submitted:

```
@users = params[:project][:users].map{|a| User.find(a) }
```

Comment: I ended up using id with this in my update

users = User.where(id: params[:user_ids])
@project.users = users

Comment: Good, but the point is, that you can't serialize the instance into the string, and read it back just like that you tried.